# How to check Dialogflow Quota via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-monitoring

One of the agents I use is exceeding the quota of operations.

I need to query this quota via a script before I do any more operations and exceed it.

I've tried the Dialogflow API but there doesn't seem to be any way to query it.

I have also tried the Monitoring API but I don't see the resource or the way to do it. The API documentation doesn´t cover this request.

Any clue how to get it?

Is there any way to check the quota consumption/current usage in real time?

Comment: Hi @JulioPorto, To check Dialogflow Quota you can go [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_quota_console)
in the console, where you can view quota usage and limits for all resources in your project. For more information about quotas and limits for use of Dialogflow, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: As I said in the question I need to query the quota via script/api/sdk. The option to view it in the console doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the option to check various quotes of Dialogflow API, its limit and current usage percentage is through the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_quota_console) page in the cloud console.

For more information about quotas and limits for use of Dialogflow, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas).

If you want the feature to query the quota via script/api/sdk, you can raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.